# set upper limit in ggplot to include label greater than the maximum value

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data range always seems to be greater than the top label in the y-axis. Is there a way I can automatically include it without manually setting limits?

e.g. in

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:11, y=c(11:17,5:2)), aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

I would like to have labels 0 and 20 appear on the y-axis and o and 12 appear on the x-axis (and the plot expand accordingly). This should be done automatically without specifying these numbers in scale options for example.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about the following solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- data.frame(x=1:11, y=c(11:17,5:2))
px <- pretty(d$x)
py <- pretty(d$y)

ggplot(d, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=px, limits=range(px)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=py, limits=range(px))
```

[image]

Comment: I admit your workaround is better than my workaround, but isn't there something in ggplot that's trimming the ends off of the pretty range in the first place?

Comment: Also, I thin the `breaks=px` argument isn't needed, right? (The bounty's yours, btw, if no one comes up with something better!)

Comment: I tried it with and without `breaks=px` and I prefer it with. If I leave it out, I'm essentially saying "let `pretty` decide what the min and max values are, but let `ggplot` decide where the breaks should be". So I think it's better to let either `pretty` control everything OR `ggplot`.

Comment: BTW I initially preferred the ggplot way of leaving off tick marks that go beyond the data, but now that I know there's a relatively straightforward way of overriding that with `pretty` to get the more standard approach to tick marks I'm _pretty_ happy.

Comment: I thought that ggplot used `pretty` to determine breaks, but now that you mention it, maybe I'm wrong on that.

Comment: To be slightly less verbose you could change `limits=c(min(px), max(px))` to `limits=range(px)`. Just throwin' that in there!

Comment: Yeah, not a bad idea!

Answer (score 10):

```
dat<-data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(11:17,5:3))
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(pretty(dat$y, n=4),18), expand=c(0.25, 0.25))
```

[image: ggplot pretty breaks]

The `pretty` function chooses nice breaks as 1, 2 or 5 times a power of 10. Then I just included 18 to that vector.

Comment: Thank you for the introduction to `pretty()`! This isn't quite what I was going for (it's not the 18 per say that I want, but automatically including the next break level above my data. In this case 20.) I think the expand argument does the trick, but I need to play with it a bit more, to make sure it expands enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe with `scale_y_continuous` and the `expand` argument:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(11:17,5:3)), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: thanks jmsigner. But when I run that code no such 18 appears. (And the +s at the beginning of the lines rather than the end of the previous line throws a wobbly.)

Comment: I think for the 18 to appear you would need the change the `breaks` argument within `scale_y_continuous`. Sorry, about the `+`

Comment: No worries. Okay, well I know how to do limits and I could do a workaround with `limits = c(0, max(17) * 1.1)`, but I wondered if there might be some more elegant solution.

Comment: I am sure there is ;), maybe some else can give a hint

Comment: My apologies, jmsigner. After updating ggplot your code totally works! Thanks! (Now I have to figure out how much to expand by in order to always show the next break...)

Answer (score 3):

So I don't think `expand` is actually the way to go about this, rather `expand_limits`.
This is clearly not the most beautiful code, but this is basically the functionality I'm looking for where the labels on the y-axis encompass the data completely.

```
dat<-data.frame(x=1:10, y=c(11:17,5:3))
ggplot(dat, aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point() + 
expand_limits(y=c(min(pretty(c(dat$y, min(dat$y) * (0.95)))), max(pretty(c(dat$y, max(dat$y) * (1.05))))))
```

[image: scales completely surrounding data]

I've assumed expand default as 0.05 and that pretty is used with defaults. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have a better answer, I will gladly drop mine to accept yours!

Comment: @amzu That was 6 months ago, so I'm afraid I don't remember :( Anyhow, my method here is much more workaround then solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried skipping the 0.95 * 1.05 multipliers?

```
expand_limits(y=c(min(pretty(c(dat$y,min(dat$y)))),max(pretty(c(dat$y,max(dat$y))))))
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jeremy but when I try it I still get points outside of the scale range.