# ggplot2 setting x and y ticks to always emcompass the data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot x vs y. Both are continuous variables. I want the x and y ticks to always bound the data. In other words, smallest xtick needs be at most min(x), largest xtick needs be at least max(x). Same is true for y as well.

I tried this:

```
seq_ticks <- function(n) {function(limits) pretty(limits, n)}
p<-ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty))+theme_bw()+geom_line(aes(y=hwy))
p <- p+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq_ticks(10))+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq_ticks(10))
```

It would even better if the outer most major grid (ggplot2 is typically placing the tics near major grids) becomes the bounding box.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds somewhat related to Tom's question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427212/set-upper-limit-in-ggplot-to-include-label-greater-than-the-maximum-value

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

```
library(ggplot2)
# evenly spaced, but not so pretty breaks
breaks.x <- with(mpg,round(seq(min(cty),max(cty),length.out=10),digits=1))
breaks.y <- with(mpg,round(seq(min(hwy),max(hwy),length.out=10),digits=1))
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy))+ 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks.x) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks.y)
```

[image]

```
# pretty breaks, with extra grid lines at the limits
breaks.x <- with(mpg,pretty(seq(min(cty),max(cty),length.out=10)))
if (min(mpg$cty)>min(breaks.x)) breaks.x[1] <- min(mpg$cty)
if (max(mpg$cty)<max(breaks.x)) breaks.x[length(breaks.x)] <- max(mpg$cty)
breaks.y <- with(mpg,pretty(seq(min(hwy),max(hwy),length.out=10)))
if (min(mpg$hwy)>min(breaks.y)) breaks.y[1] <- min(mpg$hwy)
if (max(mpg$hwy)<max(breaks.y)) breaks.y[length(breaks.y)] <- max(mpg$hwy)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cty, y=hwy))+ 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=breaks.x) + scale_y_continuous(breaks=breaks.y)
```

[image]

Comment: Both are looking good. I would pick second option for my needs. Btw, can someone tell me why just using "pretty" does not work, even though "pretty" encloses the range. Does ggplot ignore the major grids if they fall outside of the data range?