# all values not plotting while using pretty in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was looking for way to set upper y limit in ggplot to include label greater than the maximum value. I quickly found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427212/set-upper-limit-in-ggplot-to-include-label-greater-than-the-maximum-value) answer using `pretty`. However, when I plot using my data it won't plot the value for 'fire' in year 2004.

Here is my data:

```
t <- structure(list(park = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L), .Label = c("apis", "indu", "isro", "miss", "piro", "sacn", 
"slbe", "voya"), class = "factor"), loc_01 = structure(c(16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("apis", 
"indu", "isro", "miss", "non_apis", "non_indu", "non_isro", "non_miss", 
"non_piro", "non_sacn", "non_slbe", "non_voya", "piro", "sacn", 
"slbe", "voya"), class = "factor"), year = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("agriculture", "beaver", 
"blowdown", "development", "fire", "flooding", "harvest_00_20", 
"harvest_30_60", "harvest_70_90", "insect_disease_defo", "insect_disease_mort", 
"unknown"), class = "factor"), value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0832931254278862, 
0.0301695451904579, 0.0264171464103402, 0.0268075089513891, 0, 
0.0131238087762612, 0.0900844930199918, 0, 0, 0.014770372800214, 
0.0501002326005331, 0, 0, 0, 0.231917243175008, 0.108369509403789, 
0, 0.000509329143326649)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .Names = c("park", 
"loc_01", "year", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

This is the code I'm using...

```
library(ggplot2)
py <- pretty(t$value)
p <- ggplot () + geom_bar(data=t,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(breaks=py,limits=range(py))
p
```

Which produces this...

[image]

If I look at `t`
I see that there should be a 'fire' value for years 2004, 2005, and 2007. But in the stacked bar graph it is missing. I've tried the same graph without the `pretty` option and it works fine. So, my error must have something to do with use of the option. Any ideas?

```
   park loc_01 year    variable        value
1  voya   voya 2002 agriculture 0.0000000000
2  voya   voya 2003 agriculture 0.0000000000
3  voya   voya 2004 agriculture 0.0000000000
4  voya   voya 2005 agriculture 0.0000000000
5  voya   voya 2006 agriculture 0.0000000000
6  voya   voya 2007 agriculture 0.0000000000
7  voya   voya 2002      beaver 0.0832931254
8  voya   voya 2003      beaver 0.0301695452
9  voya   voya 2004      beaver 0.0264171464
10 voya   voya 2005      beaver 0.0268075090
11 voya   voya 2006      beaver 0.0000000000
12 voya   voya 2007      beaver 0.0131238088
13 voya   voya 2002    blowdown 0.0900844930
14 voya   voya 2003    blowdown 0.0000000000
15 voya   voya 2004    blowdown 0.0000000000
16 voya   voya 2005    blowdown 0.0147703728
17 voya   voya 2006    blowdown 0.0501002326
18 voya   voya 2007    blowdown 0.0000000000
19 voya   voya 2002        fire 0.0000000000
20 voya   voya 2003        fire 0.0000000000
21 voya   voya 2004        fire 0.2319172432
22 voya   voya 2005        fire 0.1083695094
23 voya   voya 2006        fire 0.0000000000
24 voya   voya 2007        fire 0.0005093291
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following OP comment to @BrodieG answer, it's as simple as (assuming the lower limit is 0, and increasing `ymax` by 25%):

```
py <- range(t$value)*1.25
p <- ggplot () + geom_bar(data=t,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(limits=py)
p
```

[image]

Should the lower limit be fixed to 0 regardless of `t$value`, then use:

```
py <- c(0, max(t$value)*1.25)
```

Comment: this might be a new question, but is there a way to ensure that the last y axis tick is always labeled? For example, right now the y axis will always be more than the range, but sometimes (with other data) the last tick mark doesn't show and thus doesn't get labeled.

Comment: note this is not entirely correct, you need to `range(tapply(t$value, t$year, sum))` before expanding.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
coord_cartesian(ylim=range(py))
```

instead of `scale_y_continuous`.  The latter gets rid of any data outside of the boundaries you define.  The former just clips the drawing.

```
library(ggplot2)
py <- pretty(t$value)
p <- ggplot () + geom_bar(data=t,aes(x=year,y=value,fill=variable),stat='identity')
p <- p + coord_cartesian(ylim=range(py))
p
```

[image]

Note that in the original **[Grammar of Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387245448)**, Wilkinson (author) strongly opposed aesthetic representations that muddied the mapping of space and values.  Among other things, he suggests cropping plots is highly misleading.  He recommends using transformed scaled (e.g. log) to deal with plots that are difficult to decipher with outliers rather than cropping.  This is from memory so I don't have specific references.

Comment: I guess what I really want is to auto buffer the ymax by X% and use that as the range. Do you have suggestion for that?

Comment: I agree with @BrodieG's comment regarding cropping the plot at the exact range of the data and is why I added my buffer comment.