# Dynamically use range of pretty breaks to set limits in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Hi I want to dynamically set the limits on a plot to make sure that there is a break above the top data point. It needs to be dynamic as I want to do all the formatting in a base plot but then be able to add different data without having to change hard coded axis limits or have a whole lot of different scenarios where I have to call get the limits first and then set them (eg. as shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427212/set-upper-limit-in-ggplot-to-include-label-greater-than-the-maximum-value)). I know I could wrap this in my own function, but I'm hoping there's a default way.

I am using `scales::pretty_breaks` to get my breaks within `scale_y_continuous`. Ideally I'd like to be able to set something along the lines of  `scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_breaks(), limits = range(pretty_breaks()))` but this doesn't work and I'm assuming the pretty_breaks only works by default within the breaks call.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
set.seed(1)
rdat <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,y=runif(1000,min = 0, max = 107))

ggplot(rdat, aes(x =x, y = y))+geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_breaks())
```

I can add this:

```
ggplot(rdat, aes(x =x, y = y))+geom_point()+
   scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_breaks(), limits = range(pretty_breaks()(rdat$y)))
```

which works but requires me to hardcode the data.frame and y label which I'm trying to avoid.

So instead of this:
[image: Instead of this]

I want this:
[image: I want this version]

Comment: *"to make sure that there is a break above the top data point"* I struggle to understand what you're trying to do. In your figure, you arrow-label "Want label to be above my top top points". Which label are you referring to? Is this about the *order* of drawing objects, e.g. label first then points as opposed to points first then label?

Comment: `scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_breaks(), expand = c(0.15,0))` works in many cases, but not all...

Comment: Hi @MauritsEvers I have added a second plot to hopefully show better. I was a labelled point on the y axis above the top of my data, ie to expand my limits to include the break above. Jon Spring I don't want to expand the limits down at the bottom, and my data ranges might be orders of magnitude different for different plots and I also find this approach often requires tweaking of the expand multiplier depending on the data

Comment: I did just realise that I can do `scale_y_continuous(expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, .15))` which solves my first problem with this approach, but still hoping someone might have another idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem crop up again a long time later and found a more rigorous (although not beautiful) approach. Posting in case other people find it helpful.

This requires a custom limits and custom breaks function. The custom breaks function is required because when you call `breaks=pretty_breaks()` this is passed the limits of the plot, but these limits are both, already adjusted by the `limits=...` and then also expanded (in line with `expand = ...` by default multipled by 0.05). So to make sure the pretty breaks line up with the limits based on the original pretty breaks you need to try and back-derive particularly the expansion. This isn't going to be 100% perfect and assumes the default expansion.

I have also included a threshold so the limits don't go below 0 which is useful for me as the numbers I am dealing with a strictly positive but might be close to 0 so a small expansion pushes it below 0. But may not be as useful to others

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
set.seed(1)
rdat <- data.frame(x = 1:1000,y=runif(1000,min = 0, max = 107))

pretty_lim <- function(x,n=5){
  #pretty_lim
  r2 <- ifelse(x <0, 0, x)
  pr <- pretty(r2,n)
  r_out <- range(pr)
  r_out
}


pretty_unexpanded <- function(x,n=5){
  #expand_limit
  if(x[1]<=0){
    r2 <- x + c(-x[1],x[1])
  }else{
    r2 <- x + c((x[2]-x[1])*0.04545455,-(x[2]-x[1])*0.04545455)
  }
  pout <-  pretty(r2,n) 
  pout
}

#expand near 0
ggplot(rdat, aes(x =x, y = y))+geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_unexpanded,limits = pretty_lim )
```

[image]

```r
#another case no where near 0
rdat2 <- rdat
rdat2$y <- rdat2$y +45

ggplot(rdat2, aes(x =x, y = y))+geom_point()

#Raw Plot
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(rdat2, aes(x =x, y = y))+geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous( breaks=pretty_unexpanded,limits = pretty_lim )

#updated plot with new limits and breaks
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>